# how to retrieve first app model data in second app in Django

Tags: javascript, java, python, ajax, django

how to retrieve first app model data in second app in Django.

I create a model `scheme_details_model` in trible app and I have to display field `scheme_title` to the `home1.html` of the theme.

```
# this is model in trible app
class scheme_details_model(models.Model):
    scheme_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    scheme_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    publish_on = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    detail_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False,
                                          null=True)
    validity_upto = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    pdf_doc_type = models.FileField(upload_to="driver_file/",
                                    validators=[validate_file_extension],
                                    null=True)
    source_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "scheme_details_table"
```

```
# view function in theme app
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from DigitalMine.tribal.models import scheme_details_model

@login_required
def home(request):
    book = scheme_details_model.objects.all()
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = book
    print(data)
    return render(request, "home1.html")
```

display "scheme_title" field as a link to redirect to another page

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to pass the data to template file. Change this code:

```
return render(request, "home1.html")
```

to:

```
return render(request, "home1.html", data)
```

And then you can access the variable into your html file like this:

```
{% for scheme in object_list %}
    <a href="#">{{ scheme.scheme_title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```